# How do you return different uibutton subclasses from func given an enum as a param?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, casting

so below I have included some of my code. This code is clearly does not compile. The error reads `Expected member name or constructor call after type name` when I try to cast my subclass types as UIButton type.

I want to be able to call this button func in my AppDelegate so I can alter the UIAppearance of the type. This is why I am returning a type and not an instance. So if I cannot use a cast should I be trying to make use of generics or am I thinking about this problem all wrong? Any insights are appreciated. Anyway, I just want to know how I can select a specific type of button so I can style it whether there is a way to do it using generics or casting.

```
enum BtnType : Int {
    case Primary
    case Secondary
}

func button(type: BtnType) -> UIButton.Type {
    var button: UIButton.Type

    switch type {
        case .Primary:
            button = PrimaryButton.Type as! UIButton.Type
        case .Secondary:
            button = SecondaryButton.Type as! UIButton.Type
        default:
            button = PrimaryButton.Type as! UIButton.Type
    }

    return button
}
```

Comment: Do you want the function to return the desired button **type**, or a new instance of that type? Creating a new instance of that type seems a lot more useful.

Comment: I want it to return the button type as I will be doing this `PrimaryButton.appearance().backgroundColor = "whatever color"` so this happens before I will instantiate any of the PrimaryButtons. however, if you have another work around feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self` on your custom button types to return the respective metatype (which are of type `Button.Type`):

```
func buttonType(for type: BtnType) -> UIButton.Type {
    let button: UIButton.Type
    switch type {
    case .Primary: button = PrimaryButton.self
    case .Secondary: button = SecondaryButton.self
    }
    return button
}
```

Note that you can say `let button: UIButton.Type` (instead of `var`) because it's exactly set once in the `switch`.

Also note that you don't need to cast `as! UIButton.Type` because `AnyButtonSubclass.self` is a `UIButton.Type`.

Example usage:

```
let b = buttonType(for: .Primary).init(type: .system) // b is a UIButton
b.setTitle("Primary", for: .normal)
```

**About `.Type` and `.self`**

(I'll just stick to classes here and don't go into compile-time types vs. runtime types to keep things simpler.)

You are probably used to using objects and classes. Objects are instances of classes. The type of an object is the class that the object is an instance of. One level higher (hence the meta),
you are dealing with classes and metaclasses. Here, the type of a class is its metaclass.

Syntactically, whenever you need or want to write a type, you can say `Foo.Type`. This can be the type of a variable, of a parameter, or as in this case, the return type of `buttonType(for:)`.
`UIButton.self` is an expression of type `UIButton.Type`. Just like you can assign a `UIButton` instance to a variable of type `UIButton`, you can assign `UIButton.self` to a variable of `UIButton.Type`.

Note that on both levels (objects and classes, classes and metaclasses), you have an "is-a" relationship. You can assign an instance of any subclass of `UIButton` to a variable of type `UIButton`.
Likewise, you can assign any `SubclassOfUIButton.self` to a variable of `UIButton.Type`.

Some hopefully illustrative code:

```
class PrimaryButton: UIButton { ... }
class SecondaryButton: UIButton { ... }

let button = PrimaryButton(type: .system)
button is PrimaryButton  // true
button is UIButton  // true
button is UIControl  // true
// etc
button is String  // false
let uibutton: UIButton = button

let buttonType: PrimaryButton.Type = PrimaryButton.self
buttonType is PrimaryButton.Type  // true
buttonType is UIButton.Type  // true
buttonType is UIControl.Type  // true
// etc
buttonType is String.Type  // false
let uiButtonType: UIButton.Type = buttonType
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for. So why can I not use type? I even had tried `.type.type` when I noticed that auto complete gave the option to do so. I guess `.self` makes sense because it hasn't been instantiated so it must be referring to the class itself, but I thought it was kind of confusing given that `UIButton.type` works. I am sure you could probably use `.self` on UIButton as well and get away with it.

Comment: I'll update my answer later to explain those things a little more. Note that I shouldn't have called the method makeButton because it doesn't actually make one but return the type for making one. I'll update this as well.

Comment: @user3832583: I renamed the function and added the section "About .Type and .self". I hope that clears things up.